# Admin can edit user's only name with not email and password in rubyonrails how to write that method please look into it and resolve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my usercontroller.rb

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

 before_action :user_logged_in, only: [:show,:edit ,:update, :index, :destroy]
 before_action :check_admin, only: [:index]
 before_action :check_correct_user, only: [:edit ,:update]

def edit

@user=User.find(params[:id])

end
```

This is update method
update

```
def update
@user=User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update(user_req)
flash[:success]="Profile Updated"
redirect_to @user
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

this is params
private

```
def user_req
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
:password_confirmation)
end
```

i created another method for check_admin

```
def check_correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user || 
current_user.admin?
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand our question correctly. Do you want users to be able to update their own name, email, and password? And admins should be able to update other users too, but only their names?

Then I would do it like this:

```
def user_req
  if current_user.admin? && @user != current_user
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  else
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

The condition is a bit more complex than expected because an admin user still needs to be able to update their own email and password.

Comment: Yes your understanding is right, but i am getting this errors
1.the form contains errors :
  Password can't be blank,
  Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters),How can i resolve this , please look

Comment: What does your `User` model look like, especially the validations?

Comment: class User < ApplicationRecord

    before_save {self.email = self.email.downcase}
    
    validates :name, presence:true ,length:{maximum:50}
    
    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    
    
    validates :email, presence:true ,length:{maximum:100} , format: {with:EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: true

    has_secure_password
    
    validates :password, presence:true , length: {minimum: 8}

end

Comment: This is my usermodel please check

Comment: Are you trying to create a user by Admin?  If the user is already created then it should have a password. You are trying to edit a user who doesn't have a password.

Comment: You are using `has_secure_password` in your `User` model. `has_secure_password` automatically defines all required validations for `password` and `password_confirmation` (see [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)). Therefore you can simple remove this line from your model: `validates :password, presence:true , length: {minimum: 8}`